# How to inherit @ConditionalOnProperty to any static inner @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I create a `@Configuration` class that holds static inner configuration classes and inherit the `@ConditionalOnProperty`?

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my.property", havingValue = "true")
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Configuration
    static class SubConfig1 {
    }

    @Configuration
    static class SubConfig2 {
    }

    ....
}
```

In this example, I want the inner classes to load only if the condition on the parent is true, so I don't have to repeat the condition for each config class. Is that possible?

Comment: so if i understand if `ConditionalOnProperty` evaluates to true then is should load three beans in total `MyConfiguration`, `SubConfig1` and `SubConfig2`?, if not can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Yes that's my goal. If the condition matches, it should load those 3 sub `@Configuration` classes. But as written, all those 3 classes are even loaded if the condition is not true.

Comment: can you show the property specified in `yml` or `properties` file?

Comment: `my.property=true`?

Comment: so you are setting it to `false` when you don't want to load config beans?

Comment: exactly. `my.property=false` should prevent all 3 sub classes without having to repeat the condition on each.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: I worked around it using the accepted approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong on all nested classes that are annotated with `@Configuration` will be loaded automatically. [With nested @Configuration classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

> When bootstrapping such an arrangement, only AppConfig need be registered against the application context. **By virtue of being a nested @Configuration class, DatabaseConfig will be registered automatically.** This avoids the need to use an @Import annotation when the relationship between AppConfig and DatabaseConfig is already implicitly clear.

So by using `@ConditionalOnProperty` you can only avoid the beans that are declared in config class, but you cannot avoid the nested classes with `@Configuration` annotation until specified by a condition

**For Example** Below approch will avoid the beans loading into `ApplicationContext` if `my.property` is `false`

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my.property", havingValue = "true")
 public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SubConfig1 getSubConfig1() {
     return new SubConfig1();
    }

  @Bean
  public SubConfig2 getSubConfig2() {
     return new SubConfig2();
    }

    static class SubConfig1 {
    }


   static class SubConfig2 {
   }


 }
```